# ES 6 to ES 5 need help fixing

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have two pieces of code that are **ES6**, but I need to use **ES5** for a class.  What is the best way to create each of these listed in **ES5**?  I am outputting these from an array and each of the values in the array needs to be on a new line.

1. `tools.forEach(tools => console.log(tools));`
2. `tools.sort().forEach(tools => console.log(tools));`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions are better received if you provide your research, and example code you've tried (in this case, what is your ES5 code you've tried? Why is it not ES5? How did you try to find what is ES5 vs ES6?). Additionally, generally it is better to ask a single question, rather than multiple.

Comment: ES5 would look something like `tools.sort();for(var i=0;i<tools.length;i++){ console.log(tools[i]);}`

Comment: You only have to convert arrow functions to normal ES5 functions. everything else is already ES5. `()=>{}` becomes `function(){}`

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance of the question.  I am new to stackoverflow and I apologize for my ignorance.  The good news is that work great!  I was able to get by piecing it together from a book I have but had some issues with ES5.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Just transpile it using `function` like so:

```
tools.forEach(function(tool) {
    console.log(tool);
});
```

And add the `sort` for the other one:

```
tools.sort().forEach(function(tool) {
    console.log(tool);
});
```

Note that although there is an implicit return in the ES6 you provided, you don't actually need it in a `forEach()` loop, which is why I have excluded it - feel free to add it back in if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this babel compiler to convert code examples from ES6 to ES5

https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=C4exBsGcDpJAnYAKAlNAZggogQwMYAWSoEkABALwB8ZeIAdnOAKbTggDmxYUKKA3EA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.4

```
tools.forEach(tools => console.log(tools));
```

becomes:

```
tools.forEach(function (tools) {
  return console.log(tools);
});
```

and

```
tools.sort().forEach(tools => console.log(tools));
```

becomes:

```
tools.sort().forEach(function (tools) {
  return console.log(tools);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is with the `=>` you can simply write it like so;

```
tools.forEach(function (tools) {
  return console.log(tools);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `=>` by using `function`

**1st**

```
tools.forEach(tools => console.log(tools));
```

**Replace by given code**

```
tools.forEach(function(tools){
    console.log(tools));
});
```

**2nd**

```
tools.sort().forEach(tools => console.log(tools));
```

**Replace by given code**

```
tools.sort().forEach(function(tools){
    console.log(tools));
});
```

This is the link to convert [ES6 to ES5](https://babeljs.io/en/repl)